# Using BeautifulSoup To Extract Specific TD Table Elements Text?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I trying to extract IP Addresses from a autogenerated HTML table using the BeautifulSoup library and im having a little trouble.

The HTML is structured like so:

```
<html>
<body>
    <table class="mainTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>IP</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="hello.html">127.0.0.1<a></td>
            <td><img src="uk.gif" /><a href="uk.com">uk</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="hello.html">192.168.0.1<a></td>
            <td><img src="uk.gif" /><a href="us.com">us</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="hello.html">255.255.255.0<a></td>
            <td><img src="uk.gif" /><a href="br.com">br</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The small code below extracts the text from the two td rows but i only need the IP data, not the IP and Country data:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("data.htm"))

table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'mainTable'})
for row in table.findAll("a"):
print(row.text)
```

this outputs:

```
127.0.0.1
uk
192.168.0.1
us
255.255.255.0
br
```

What i need is the IP `table.tbody.tr.td.a` elements text and not the country `table.tbody.tr.td.img.a` elements.

Are there any experienced users of BeautifulSoup who would have any inkling on how to to this selection and extraction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This gives you the right list:

```
>>> pred = lambda tag: tag.parent.find('img') is None
>>> list(filter(pred, soup.find('tbody').find_all('a')))
[<a href="hello.html">127.0.0.1<a></a></a>, <a></a>, <a href="hello.html">192.168.0.1<a></a></a>, <a></a>, <a href="hello.html">255.255.255.0<a></a></a>, <a></a>]
```

just apply `.text` on the elements of this list.

There are multiple empty `<a></a>` tags in above list because the `<a>` tags in the html are not closed properly. To get rid of them, you may use

```
pred = lambda tag: tag.parent.find('img') is None and tag.text
```

and ultimately:

```
>>> [tag.text for tag in filter(pred, soup.find('tbody').find_all('a'))]
['127.0.0.1', '192.168.0.1', '255.255.255.0']
```

Comment: nice approach and useful solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a little regular expression for extracting the ip address. BeautifulSoup with regular expression is a nice combination for scraping.

```
ip_pat = re.compile(r"^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$")
for row in table.findAll("a"):
    if ip_pat.match(row.text):
        print(row.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Search just first `<td>` for each row in `tbody`:

```
# html should contain page content:
[row.find('td').getText() for row in bs4.BeautifulSoup(html).find('tbody').find_all('tr')]
```

or maybe more readable:

```
rows = [row in bs4.BeautifulSoup(html).find('tbody').find_all('tr')]
iplist = [row.find('td').getText() for row in rows]
```

Answer (score 1):

First note that the HTML is not well-formed. It is not closing the `a` tags. There are **two** `<a>` tags started here:

```
<a href="hello.html">127.0.0.1<a>
```

If you print `table` you'll see BeautifulSoup is parsing the HTML as:

```
<td>
<a href="hello.html">127.0.0.1</a><a></a>
</td>
...
```

Each `a` is followed by an empty `a`.

---

Given the presence of those extra `<a>` tags, if you want every **third** `<a>` tag, then

```
for row in table.findAll("a")[::3]:
    print(row.get_text())
```

suffices:

```
127.0.0.1
192.168.0.1
255.255.255.0
```

On the other hand, if the occurrence of `<a>` tags is not so regular and you only want that `<a>` tags with no previous sibling (such as, but not limited to `<img>`), then

```
for row in table.findAll("a"):
    sibling = row.findPreviousSibling()
    if sibling is None:
        print(row.get_text())
```

would work.

---

If you have [lxml](http://lxml.de/), the criteria can be expressed more succinctly using XPath:

```
import lxml.html as LH
doc = LH.parse("data.htm")
ips = doc.xpath('//table[@class="mainTable"]//td/a[not(preceding-sibling::img)]/text()')
print(ips)
```

The XPath used above has the following meaning:

```
//table                            select all <table> tags
    [@class="mainTable"]           that have a class="mainTable" attribute
//                                 from these tags select descendants
  td/a                             which are td tags with a child <a> tag
    [not(preceding-sibling::img)]  such that it does not have a preceding sibling <img> tag
    /text()                        return the text of the <a> tag
```

It does take a little time to [learn XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp), but once you learn it you may never want to use BeautifulSoup again.